# tikz-uml Warning underfull hbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

i'm stuck and have no idea what the problem is. I'd like to draw a UML component diagram with tkz-uml package. The drawing ist working fine, but i get a emty Box Message.

```
pdflatex> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)
```

How can I prevent it?

Here is some sample code

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\pgfdeclarelayer{component0}
\pgfdeclarelayer{package0}
\pgfsetlayers{package0,component0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
    \begin{umlpackage}{A}
        \umlbasiccomponent[x=0,y=0]{B}
        \umlbasiccomponent[x=3.5,y=3.5]{C}
        \umlbasiccomponent[x=7,y=0]{D}
    \end{umlpackage}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I downloaded the last version of `tikz-uml` and I get many errors.

Comment: this does not resolve the Problem, but it will help: adding "\hbadness=10000" bevor "\begin{tikzpicture}"

Comment: The most likely cause is some `\par` or `\\ ` inside the package code somewhere. The underfull box does *not* happen with an empty `umlpackage` environment.

Comment: With version 1.0b of `tikz-uml` I get neither errors nor underfull boxes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not reproducible after updating the relevant packages.